# Check if the letters of one string are in another string

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Okey so basically I have to check if one string has the same letters of another string. Both strings are obtained via ***input()***.

I don't want to double check if a letter is in the other string, so if I already checked that letter I want to skip to the next letter.

The code I have for now is this:

```
str1, str2 = list(input()), list(input()) 

if len(str1) > len(str2):
    str = str1
else: 
    str = str2

for x in str:
    c = 0
    if x in str2:
        c += 1
if c != 0:
    print("Both have the same letters!") 
else: 
    print("Nope there are some letters missing..")
```

I don't know if I should work with the lists instead of using a counter.. please a detailled explanation of the solution or some good quality guidance would be very appreciated! <3

Comment: Currently your logic does not check for presence of all letters. For example - `str1 = 'foo', str2='fbar'`. The output results in **Both have the same letters!**. One approach is to keep the letters of both the strings in 2 different sets and check if sets are equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting strings to sets of individual symbols remove duplicate symbols, so we can simply compare them:

```
if set(str1) == set(str2):
    print("Both have the same letters!") 
else:
    print("Nope there are some letters missing..")
```

---

*Note:*

As the *order of elements in sets is not important*, we may even *compare them*, e. g.

```
if set(str1) <= set(str2):        # <= means "is subset" in this context
    print("All symbols in str1 are in str2, too.")
```

or

```
if set(str1) < set(str2):        # < means "is a proper subset" in this context
    print("All symbols in str1 are in str2, too, "
          "but str2 has at least 1 symbol not contained in str1.")
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks a lot! If I understood the method set() well what it does is make a dictionary? Sorry if the question is ducmb but Im trying to learn step by step. I really appreciate everyones help!

Comment: No, `set()` *doesn't make a dictionary*, it makes a *set*, which is itself a *special type of collection*, corresponding to the *mathematical* definition of the *set*. E. g.: `set("abcacab")` will be `{"a", "b", "c"}` (or `{"c", "a", "b"}`, which is the same - the order of elements doesn't matter) . (An example of a dictionary may be `{1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"}` - it is enclosed in the *same pair of curly brackets (`{})`*, but consists of pairs `key`: `value`, delimited with a colon (`:`).)

Comment: Okey now I fully understand the difference thanks a lot! You are a great person for teching me this without asking anything!

Answer (score 0):

Some issues with the code are that, str2 is always used for comparison even if str2 is longer than str1

```
for x in str:
    c = 0
    if x in str2:
```

Next, c is set to 0 for every character in str, Instead you can have a counter to count the number of chars not in the other string

This should do the job

```
str1, str2 = list(input()), list(input()) 

if len(str1) > len(str2):
    str = str1
    compared_string = str2
else: 
    str = str2
    compared_string = str1

not_in_other_string = 0
for x in str:
    if x  not in compared_string:
        not_in_other_string += 1
if not_in_other_string == 0:
    print("Both have the same letters!") 
else: 
    print("Nope there are some letters missing..")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to find if all of the characters in one string are in some larger string.

You could use `unique = ''.join(set(substring))` to get a list of chars in the substring and then make a `list comprehension` to get all the chars in the larger string.

Here is my example:

```
unique = ''.join(set(substring))
not_in = [char for char in unique if char not in superstring]
```

Now you can check not_in to see if it is null, otherwise there was a char in the substring that was not in the superstring.

For example:

```
superstring = "hello"
substring = "xllo"

unique = ''.join(set(substring))
not_in = [char for char in unique if char not in superstring]

print not_in
>>>['x']

print not_in == []
>>>False
```

Typically, the preferred way to do things in python is using list comprehensions or use some built in function that already checks strings for you, rather than the C style where you go through a loop and check letter for letter explicitly. This is the idiomatic way of pythonic programming.

Breaking apart the list comprehension we have a loop like this:

```
   for char in unique: 
        if char not in superstring:
             char #char meets conditions so it is the value used in [char ...
```

Here would be the modification I would make

```
str1, str2 = input(), input()

unique = ''.join(set(str1))
not_in = [char for char in unique if char not in str2]

if not_in == []:
    print("Both have the same letters!") 
else: 
    print("Nope there are some letters missing..")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1, str2 = input().split()

if len(str1) > len(str2):
    string_to_check= str1
    string_from_which_to_check = str2
else: 
    string_to_check = str2

string_from_which_to_check = str1    
not_in_other_string  = set(string_to_check) - set(string_from_which_to_check)
if len(not_in_other_string )==0:
     print("character are present in string")
else:
    print("{} not present in string".format(str(not_in_other_string )))
```